# How to redraw mouse movement on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I have an array of  tuples in javascript. Is there an existing library that lets me view the mouse movements the user performed?

Ideally something that lets me replay the captured data from the beginning to the end. It would look like a video player (ie play, pause, adjust replay speed), but instead of a video you would see how the mouse cursor moved. This visualization would be on HTML5 canvas (ie. a square of white pixels representing the cursor that's moving through in a black HTML canvas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough to accomplish without a library.

- Listen for mousemove events
- On mousemove, add each mouse position to a points array
- When requested, run an `requestAnimationFrame` loop that redraws each point from the points array.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var points=[];
var nextTime=0;
var nextN=0;
var duration=1000/60;
ctx.lineCap='round';

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});

$('#fast').on('click',function(){ duration=1000/60; beginRedrawing(); });
$('#slow').on('click',function(){ duration=1000/15; beginRedrawing(); });

function beginRedrawing(){
  if(points.length<2){return;}
  nextN=1;
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.strokeStyle=randomColor();
  requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get current mouse position
  ctx.lineWidth=7;
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  points.length=0;
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
  // Set dragging flag
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get current mouse position          
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // Clear dragging flag
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get current mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
  var n=points.length-1;
  lineSegment(points[n-1],points[n]);
}

function lineSegment(p0,p1){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p0.x,p0.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function redraw(time){
  if(nextN>points.length-1){return;}
  if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(redraw);return;}
  nextTime=time+duration;
  lineSegment(points[nextN-1],points[nextN]);
  nextN++;
  requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}

function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag to create polyline then click a redraw button below.</h4>
<button id=fast>Fast Redraw</button>
<button id=slow>Slow Redraw</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries that do what you described, but creating an array of the positions and then using that should do roughly what you want.

```
//Capture all mouse movements on the browser window.
document.onmousemove = mousePos;

//Store all previous mouse locations
var ary = [];

function mousePos (e) {

    //Log the current mouse position
    ary.push({X: e.pageX, Y: e.pageY});
}
```

Now you can loop through the array to get your mouse movement.

```
function replay() {

  for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {

    //Draw a point wherever the mouse moved.
    ctx.fillRect(ary[i].X, ary[i].Y, 2, 2);  
  }
}
```

You can add in a delay of your duration to playback at whichever speed you like.